# Error: Could not find or load main class riotcmd.riot in apache jena

Tags: rdf, jena

I downloaded and extracted the jena-4.7.0-source-release.zip on a server using terminal. when I use the riot command it gives me an error. The details can be seen in the snapshot [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nzhWs.png) what should I do to getrid of this error.

I could not find proper help on the internet.

Comment: why did you download the sources and not the binary release?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out this mistake